# Lyapunov function for system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I am searching for a proper Lyapunov function, supporting the following system of differential equations.

$$
\begin{array} {}
\dot{x_1}=a\;x_1-b\;x_1^3 \\
\dot{x_2}=a\;x_2-b\;x_2^3
\end{array}
$$

$a,b\in \mathbb{R}$  are constant parameters of the system.

Would appreciate, if anyone could help with such a function.

Comment: Most candidated look like $L(x) := \langle x, Ax \rangle$ where $A$ is a s.p.d. $2\times 2$ matrix. I'd first try a diagonal one.

Comment: Is it correct that the two equations are uncoupled? Then you can assess the stability of each separately, which is simplified as they are both instances of the same equation.

Comment: @LutzLehmann yes. It took me many hours to transform the original system to the uncoupled modes. Do you mean I could set two Lyapunovs?

Comment: For large $x_k$ the cubic term dominates and thus the vector field points towards zero. This means that the stable equilibria are the outside points $\pm\sqrt{a/b}$. You need to use that in the construction of the Lyapunov function so that it has minima at the correct points.

Comment: @LutzLehmann practically seems that all states of the system must be on either a potential $V(x_i)=-(a/2)x_i^2+(b/4)x_i^4; i={1,2}$. Having that said, it is possible to refer to two uncoupled potentials. But it is not possible to have them coupled in one picture.

Comment: Or more compactly $V(x)=(bx^2-a)^2$, the difference being constants and constant factors.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes, brilliant! Perhaps it would be an idea to set the question the other way, when would an uncoupled system have a Lyapunov function at all. Hmmmm!

Answer (score 0):

Well, since the system is decoupled, let's take $\dot{x} = - a x - b x^{3}$. Begin by choosing a Lyapunov function candidate such that $V(0) = 0$, and $V(x) > 0$ for all $x$ with $x \neq 0$
$$
V(x) = \frac{1}{2} x^{2}.
$$
Taking the time derivative of $V$ along the trajectory of the system yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \dot{V}(x) &= x \dot{x} \\
 \dot{V}(x) &= x \left(- a x - b x^{3}\right) \\
 \dot{V}(x) &= - a x^{2} - b x^{4}. \\
\end{aligned}
$$
**Case #1**: If $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ for all $x$ with $x \neq 0$, which implies that the $x = 0$ is asymptotically stable.

**Case #2**: If $a > 0$ and $b < 0$, then $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ for $|x| < \sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$ with $x \neq 0$, which implies that the origin is asymptotically stable but surrounded by an unstable limit cycle, that is outside of $x = \pm \sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$. Its region of attraction is the interior of the limit cycle, and the boundary of the region of attraction is the limit cycle itself. The region of attraction can be enlarged by increasing $\sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$.

**Case #3**: If $a < 0$ and $b > 0$, then $\dot{V}(x) < 0$ for $|x| > \sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$ with $x \neq 0$, which implies that the origin is unstable but surrounded by a stable limit cycle, that is outside of $x = \pm \sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$. Practical stabilization can be achieved by decreasing $\sqrt{|\frac{a}{b}|}$.

**Case #4**: If $a < 0$ and $b < 0$, then $\dot{V}(x) > 0$ for all $x$ with $x \neq 0$, which implies that the origin is unstable.

Comment: You changed the equation by giving the first term a minus sign? Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Ah! My apologies.  Thanks for spotting that. I hope @al-Hwarizmi can still benefit from the analysis regarding the selection of values for $a$ and $b$. Is it necessary to edit that?